Does the noise model in the built-in surface-code circuit in Stim correspond to circuit-level noise?
In Stim, there is a built-in surface code circuit like this:
    "surface_code:rotated_memory_z",
    rounds=9,
    distance=3,
    after_clifford_depolarization=0.001,
    after_reset_flip_probability=0.001,
    before_measure_flip_probability=0.001,
    before_round_data_depolarization=0.001)

The circuit above is used in getting_started.ipynb of Stim. Does the noise model in this circuit correspond to circuit-level noise?
The reason I am thinking about it is that I had questions while looking at the circuit:

Does it include idling noise?
For example,

TICK
DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
H 2 11 16 25
DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 2 11 16 25
TICK

in this circuit, during the Hadamard gate, the qubits other than 2 11 16 25 should be idling, but 9, 13, 14, 18 are not included as noisy qubits. What is the reason?

Also, what is the reason of introducing before_round_data_depolarization? If I understand correctly, this noise should be included in the phenomenological noise, but should not be in the circuit-level noise.



Does the noise model in this circuit correspond to circuit-level noise?

Yes, it's circuit noise. It puts noise throughout the circuit, resulting in things like hook errors being present.
However, what you should really be asking is "what kind of circuit noise is this?". It's not "uniform depolarizing circuit noise", which would have more idling noise. It's not "si1000 circuit noise". It's just some random noise model I threw together to help write examples for people getting started with stim. I wanted "here's an example circuit" to be 1 line instead of 100 lines.
The intention of stim's circuit generation is not to produce a circuit with a perfect noise model that people can use for research. That's essentially impossible, or at least horrendously complicated, because different people want different things and what they want drifts over time. Some people want per-qubit noise variations, some want variations over time, some want CZ gates instead of CX gates, some want different gate orderings, some want leakage, some want crosstalk, etc etc etc. Including all that stuff would defeat the circuit generation's purpose of being a simple getting started helper.
(If you want specific circuit noise, my recommendation is to write python code that takes a noiseless circuit and adds the noise to it.)

what is the reason of introducing before_round_data_depolarization? If I understand correctly, this noise should be included in the phenomenological noise, but should not be in the circuit-level noise.

That field was included so it was easy to make phenom noise, which is a common simple type of noise people are familiar with. To get it they can set before_round_data_depolarization and before_measure_flip_probability but not the other fields.
It can also be used to emulate the fact that measurement takes a long time, so there's more idling error at round transitions (waiting for the measurements) than within rounds.
